# scroll parent to position given child in the middle of the visible area using javascript/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a `<UL>` with 10 `<LI>` elements in it, each of which is largish (say 200-300px high). I also have a  bunch of surrogates for these items, which are small and always visible. When the user clicks on one of these surrogates, I would like to scroll the `<UL>` to cause the corresponding `<LI>` item to be positioned in the *middle* of the visible portion of the `<UL>` (unless it is one of the top or bottom elements).

I've looked at a bunch of examples already that use `scrollTop:` and cannot figure out how to specify the parameter correctly. I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/Jqaxn/) to illustrate the problem.

**Clarification**:

The scrolling must operate on the list, not on the `BODY` element; it must also have a scroll bar that operates the list scrolling manually. The list is just one component in a complex UI, and the rest of the elements must be not be scrolled by this operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqaxn/3/)**

Is this what you need? I changed your markup a little bit. This is the function I used for the scrolling:

```
$('.nav li a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var itemTop = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    var itemHeight = $($(this).attr('href')).height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:itemTop + itemHeight/2 - windowHeight/2},500)
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to keep the links or "surrogates" always visible on top, then try **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqaxn/4/)** with updated styles

**UPDATE 2**

New attempt **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jqaxn/5/)** you may just need to adjust the list height

Comment: This is close, but I don't want to scroll the entire page; I only want to scroll the list.

Comment: When I made the original example, I used a fixed nav for convenience. This scrolling really should only scroll the `UL` and it should also have a scroll bar that the user can scroll manually.

Comment: did you check this one here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jqaxn/4/, links are fixed on top and it has a scroll bar

Comment: Sorry, the scroll bar is not on the `UL`, it is on the body; this is not appropriate for combining it with other elements. The scroll bar must be on the list itself, and the list will not fill the body.

Comment: To get this to work in my other code, where the list had a non-trivial offset from the top of the page, I had to subtract the top of the container from the `scrollToTop:` amount.